# bluetooth eventListener "advertisementreceived" suddenly stopped

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-bluetooth

after 30sec started, it make eventListener silence

```
const start = () => {
      navigator.bluetooth
        .requestLEScan({
          acceptAllAdvertisements: true,
          keepRepeatedDevices: true,
        })
      navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener('advertisementreceived', event => {
        console.log(event.eveice.id, event)
      })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please [file a Web Bluetooth issue in Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs) for this. It is likely a bug our team can take a look at.